# How to replace the multiple different words with a single character/word in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

**Note: Without chaining replace method (or) looping the characters in for loop (or) list comprehension**

```
input_string = "the was is characters needs to replaced by empty spaces"

input_string.replace("the","").replace("was","").replace("is","").strip()
```

output: 'characters needs to replaced by empty spaces'

Is there any direct way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use python regex module(re.sub) to replace multiple characters with a single character:

```
input_string = "the was is characters needs to replaced by empty spaces"

import re
re.sub("the|was|is","",input_string).strip()
```

'characters needs to replaced by empty spaces'

Comment: Nice! Much cleaner than setting up a list of target words and looping through replace cycles. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This should help..

```
input_string = "the was is characters needs to replaced by empty spaces"
words_to_replace=['the', 'was','is']
print(input_string)
for words in words_to_replace:
    input_string =  input_string.replace(words, "")

print(input_string.strip())
```